# MariaDB WordPress "error establishing database connection" debug and root cause fix

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb

I have a VPS (CentOS 7.2, 2GB ram) that runs basically just a simple low traffic WordPress site. The database crashes on average once a week, resulting in the infamous "error establishing database connection" page when I visit my site.

I've ruled out database credential problems and plugin problems.

Restarting the DB with `sudo systemctl restart mariadb.service` *always* fixes the problem.

I'm determined to seek out and fix the root cause, but not sure how I should go about it. Do I have to turn on logging on MariaDB? Or should I turn on WordPress debug mode using `define('WP_DEBUG', true)`, or both? What should I be looking for?

Comment: you should start checking the logs for mariadb, and also the syslog

Comment: Start with the existing logs.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with logging and debugging with MariaDB; is there only one type of log or more than one log? Any how do I view it? Any links to good tutorials would be appreciated.

Comment: I came across [this Q&A](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25165/intermittent-mysql-crashes-with-error-fatal-error-cannot-allocate-memory-for-t) and though I haven't thoroughly reviewed the accepted answer yet, I think it's what I'm looking for.